# Windows 8 Evaluation Copy check for days left

Tags: windows-8

I have a Windows 8 Evaluation Copy that had a 90 day deadline when I installed it. How do I check how much time I have left to use the OS, and what are the drawbacks I will face in the Evaluation copy when compared to RTM?

Comment: the 90 day eval is Enterprise, so it has more features that Professional or the standard.  The big drawback is that if you do decide to go with Windows 8, you'll need to do a clean install - you can't upgrade from the eval to the full.  I'm not sure how to check the time limit.

Comment: Have you tried `slmgr /xpr`?

Answer (score 11):

Open a command prompt and use `slmgr.vbs /dli` or `slmgr.vbs –dli` to see the license information which will give your remaining time, to the minute.

Below are all the commands to check the license.

- To see current license information of W8:

  ```
  slmgr /dli
  ```
- To see detailed information of the current license:

  ```
  slmgr /dlv
  ```
- To see expiration date of the current license:

  ```
  slmgr /xpr
  ```
- To extend current license grace period, type the following command:

  ```
  slmgr /rearm
  ```

[Source](http://www.technize.net/download-windows-8-enterprise-rtm-with-180-day-activation/?ModPagespeed=noscript)

Comment: Also works with Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

The number of days you have left will be on the bottom right corner of your desktop. Once the evaluation is over the system will have its wallpaper changed to a plain back one, reboot every hour and you will get reminders its not genuine windows.You cannot upgrade from it into a new installation.

Biggest drawback here is you have an install that will work at most 9 months (3 months a trial, with three rearms if its allowed), and activations will only work till august 13 next year

The evaluation copy is an evaluation copy (holy [tautology](http://xkcd.com/703/) batman!). Its fine for throwing onto a VM to see if something will work, or for a copy for testing something on the short term. The Standard(core) and Pro releases are  for systems you *actuallly care to see running properly on the long term*.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Run** and execute `winver` to check the status your trial.